# How can bindings for azure function be added at compile time with MSBuild?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, powershell, azure, msbuild

I have an azure function C# project in visual studio which has a few service bus topic triggers.  I have a powershell script which can be run to copy the function.json files generated in bin and convert them to queue bindings.  The only problem is that azure functions introduce a private target in msbuild after the Build target called [_GenerateFunctionsPostBuild](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-vs-build-sdk/blob/master/src/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions.MSBuild/Targets/netstandard1.0/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions.Build.targets#L21) .  So I am trying to look for a way to run a powershell script after this step so my changes dont get erased by the unique builds for azure functions.

Comment: Any update for this issue? Have you resolved this issue? If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Answer (score 0):

> So I am trying to look for a way to run a powershell script after this step so my changes dont get erased by the unique builds for azure functions.

To accomplish this, you can add a custom to execute the powershell script after the target `_GenerateFunctionsPostBuild`, like `<Target Name="InvokePowerShell" AfterTargets="_GenerateFunctionsPostBuild">`.

Details steps:

1. Right your project, select Edit `YourProjectName.csproj`.
2. At the very end of the project, just before the end-tag `</Project>`
   , place below scripts:

   ```
   <Target Name="InvokePowerShell" AfterTargets="_GenerateFunctionsPostBuild">

     <PropertyGroup>
       <PowerShellExe Condition=" '$(PowerShellExe)'=='' ">
       %WINDIR%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
       </PowerShellExe>
       <ScriptLocation Condition=" '$(ScriptLocation)'=='' ">
       C:\Path With Spaces\LogDeploy.ps1
       </ScriptLocation>
       <LogFileLocation Condition=" '$(LogFileLocation)'=='' ">
       C:\Path With Spaces\ContactManagerDeployLog.txt
       </LogFileLocation>
     </PropertyGroup>
     <Exec Command="$(PowerShellExe) -NonInteractive -executionpolicy Unrestricted 
                -command &quot;&amp; { 
                         &amp;&apos;$(ScriptLocation)&apos; 
                         &apos;$(LogFileLocation)&apos; 
                         &apos;$(MSDeployComputerName)&apos;} &quot;" />

   </Target>
   ```

Then the powershell script would be executed after the target `_GenerateFunctionsPostBuild`.

For [Target Build Order](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee216359.aspx) and [Running Windows PowerShell Scripts from MSBuild Project Files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/deployment/advanced-enterprise-web-deployment/running-windows-powershell-scripts-from-msbuild-project-files) for some more details.

Hope this helps.